# Predicate fetch all objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I'm trying to make a NSPredicate for getting specific objects. The problem is that the NSPredicate fetch all objects instead of only the specific objects. What am i doing wrong?

my code look like this:

```
- (void)fetchDevices {
    // Fetch the devices from persistent data store

    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    devices = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Songs"];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Songs" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    // retrive the objects with a given value for a certain property
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"%d == %d", currentRow,      [device valueForKey:@"selectedRow"]];

    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

}
```

Properties and variables:

```
@property (strong) NSMutableArray *devices;
currentRow = indexPath.row;
[device valueForKey:@"selectedRow"]
```

[device valueForKey:@"selectedRow"] (This is a INT which is stored in my core data entity)

Comment: In your predicate format, you want toe specify a property name, e.g. `NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"songName == %@', name]`

Comment: As @BlackRider has shown, the left side of the predicate should be the name of the attribute on the Song entity that you want to filter by. What's the name of the attribute?

Comment: The attribute is selectedRow. Should it be like this then? (NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"selectedRow == %@', name, currentrow])??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell from your question, because it's not clear what attributes exist on the `Songs` entity or how you want to match them. However the main problem with this predicate:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"%d == %d", currentRow,      [device valueForKey:@"selectedRow"]];
```

...is that it does not *attempt* to match anything on the `Songs` entity. The predicate string needs to include one of the attribute names from the entity type you're fetching. Or, if you have the attribute name in a local variable (maybe that's what `[device valueForKey:@"selectedRow"]` is?) you need to use `%K` in the predicate. What you have is a predicate where both sides are integer values, and I guarantee that the attribute *name* is not an integer.

Again, I can't tell you what your predicate should be without a better explanation of what you're trying to do. But the left side of the format string does need either a literal attribute name or a `%K` matching an attribute name in order to filter effectively.